# gstreamer, injecting metadata from file source: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link filesrc0 to mux

Tags: metadata, gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer 1.0, and when I ask its version number, it tells me gst-launch-1.0 version 1.6.0.  According to documentation on injecting metadata (at http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Gstreamer_cheat_sheet) this version supports injecting KLV metadata, and I don't need to apply any patches.

Ultimately, I'd like to inject metadata from a named fifo, but for now, I'd be happy to just get it to work from a regular file.  I've tried quite a number of different configurations, but every one always gives me essentially the same error.  Without getting complicated yet, I'm starting out trying to do something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 mpegtsmux name=mux filesrc location=textfile ! application/x-metadata,standard=klv ! mux.metadata0 mux. ! filesink location=x.avi
```

Actually, the docs are kinda confusing, so it's not clear when piping into the mux's metadata if I'm supposed to use "mux.metadata0" (based on error messages I've seen), "mux.metadata_0", or literally "mux.metadata_%d".  I have tried all of those.  I always get this error (and nothing else):

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link filesrc0 to mux
```

Unless I put a queue before the mux, like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 mpegtsmux name=mux filesrc location=textfile ! application/x-metadata,standard=klv ! queue ! mux.metadata0 mux. ! filesink location=x.avi
```

Then it tells me just:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link queue0 to mux
```

So it seems like the problem is with getting the metadata into the mux, not from the file.

Of course, I ultimately want to mux with actual video, so I have tried command lines that include a video source going into the mux.  Similar errors.  I've tried inserting queues.  I have tried eliminating "application/x-metadata,standard=klv", and I've tried replacing it with 'meta/x-klv' that I have seen in other examples. I have tried to find out if there's some kind of "encoder" that metadata is supposed to go through.

I have also tried directly injecting the metadata into the mux like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=textfile blocksize=1 ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=x.avi
```

And that gives me a much longer error message:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

(gst-launch-1.0:10927): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time_full: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:mpegtsmux0: Could not create handler for stream
Additional debug info:
/home/oren/var-som-mx6-yocto-jethro/build_x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/1.6.0-r0/gst-plugins-bad-1.6.0/gst/mpegtsmux/mpegtsmux.c(811): mpegtsmux_create_streams (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:mpegtsmux0
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I was thinking that maybe it didn't like not having a video source, so I tried this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=textfile blocksize=1 ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=x.avi imxv4l2src ! queue ! vpuenc_h264 ! mux.
```

But I just got this:

```
====== IMXV4L2SRC: 4.0.9 build on Jun 14 2016 14:30:22. ======
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
[INFO]  Product Info: i.MX6Q/D/S
====== VPUENC: 4.0.9 build on Jun 14 2016 14:30:32. ======
    wrapper: 1.0.65 (VPUWRAPPER_ARM_LINUX Build on Jun 14 2016 14:11:21)
    vpulib: 5.4.33
    firmware: 3.1.1.46072

(gst-launch-1.0:12249): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time_full: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
[INFO]  ringBufferEnable 0, chromaInterleave 0, mapType 0, linear2TiledEnable 0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:mux: Could not create handler for stream
Additional debug info:
/home/oren/var-som-mx6-yocto-jethro/build_x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/1.6.0-r0/gst-plugins-bad-1.6.0/gst/mpegtsmux/mpegtsmux.c(811): mpegtsmux_create_streams (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:mux
Execution ended after 0:00:00.661556333
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The metadata I want to insert will be in KLV format and (correct me if I'm wrong), I have to pre-format it that way.  But the docs are clear enough that the mux just blindly inserts whatever you give it into the container, so I could put plaintext in there, and I could extract it on the other end.

Can anyone please help me figure out how I can successfully inject metadata through the mux?

Thanks.

P.S. I really am not set up to try to build a newer version of gstreamer for this embedded system.  If at all possible I need to get this working with the installed version of gstreamer.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am trying to do exactly the same thing, right down to the named FIFO.

Comment: Any help for this? I have the same error